# In Scrum, where does the detail sit?

Tags: scrum

We've been using Scrum on a few projects now with varying success and I now have a query relating to documentation.

In Scrum, you obviously have the product backlog ("The application begins by bringing up the last document the user was working with.") and the sprint task backlog ("Implement forgot password screen").  However, in all the examples I have seen, these two items are fairly high level in terms of detail (being designed on fit on a post-it note).

So, where does the detail sit?  Let's say the client has some very specific requirements for a stock management screen, or has a complex API that needs to be integrated with on the back end, where is this documented, how and who captures this information?  Is it seperate to the backlog but populated on a just-in-time basis or some other way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about project management, not programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Sprint backlog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(development)#Sprint_backlog)

> The sprint backlog is a greatly
>   detailed document containing
>   information about how the team is
>   going to implement the requirements
>   for the upcoming sprint. Tasks are
>   broken down into hours with no task
>   being more than 16 hours. If a task is
>   greater than 16 hours, it should be
>   broken down further. Tasks on the
>   sprint backlog are never assigned,
>   rather tasks are signed-up for by the
>   team members as they like.

Comment: This suggests a single, large document, electronic or otherwise, but I was under the impression that each task is in effect a separate document -- something that would fit on an index card. Am I confusing XP with SCRUM?

Answer (score 3):

Detail can sit in a wiki available to the whole team and editable by the whole team.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is as simple as it sounds. We've seen challenges with the detail part as well. Lets say if we're developing on a story that requires capturing simple contact information for lets say a CRM system. I now have the stories from the PO and we went through the sprint planning meeting and understood the first 5 stories that meets our velocity. However its always a struggle on capturing all the details of the conversation, for example how the screen needs to be laid out, what are the 20+ fields you need to have on the screen, can some of these fields lookup information from other tables/views etc.
Who captures those details, should it be the PO or developer and whats the best practice for storing these details. We're right now trying to use wiki's for this, however it becomes an overhead in trying to maintain the action items on who needs to update which details and by when.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that specific requirements such as this are handled by the product owner. They will liase with the client during Sprint Planning 2 and update the tasks with specfic requirements as needed - hence why the Product Owner is a optional attendee of the Sprint Planning 2 meeting. This gives you a hybrid of Just-in-Time and Sprint Planning 2 population of the specifics. Anything that isn't satisfied by the time you come to work on the task will be an impediment and should be dealt with a the daily scrum, by the product owner.

As the development is Agile when using Scrum you shouldn't find too much of an issues getting requirements just in time.